# Is there a clean way to embed a url in a razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view in an ASP.NET MVC app:

```
@Html.Partial("_Comments", Model)
```

I want to make this partial a "plugin" that can be called from other apps.  So, I created a separate action in my controller to return this partial view alone:

```
public ActionResult Embed()
{
    return View("_Comments", new CommentsModel());
}
```

This action can then be accessed via the URL [root]/Comments/Embed and returns the partial view's HTML.

Is there a clean way to embed the response from this URL in a separate MVC razor view (in an entirely different app)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
@Html.Raw(new WebClient().DownloadString("[root]/Comments/Embed"))
```

Comment: that's kinda scary view code...maybe pop that sucker in an htmlhelper

Comment: What scares you about this code?  I'm looking for a solution that my colleauges can easily implement without having to include or write too much additional code.

Comment: because it's downloading that on the server...if that site ever goes down, so would this page (unless you set a shorter timeout). I'd prefer ajax solution.

Comment: or at the very least a little exception handling and timeout configuring in a helper method.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a clean way to embed the response from this URL in a separate MVC razor view (in an entirely different app)?

This means client side code, for example:

```
function getComments() {
     $.ajax({ url: '[root]/Comments/Embed',
             iframe: true, 
             success: function (data) {
         $("#target-id").html(data);
     }
     });
 }
```

**Edit**

In case you use [this ajax plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/), if you set
`iframe: true`
then you access cross domain by iframe transparenlty

Comment: I had tried this approach before coming to stackoverflow.  This has problem with cross-domain requests.  I get the error: `Origin http://localhost:42347 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: I'd like to avoid using `iframe` if at all possible.  I tried a few things with `JSONP`.  Got as far as getting the response, but since it's not JSON, it throws a parse error.

Comment: which plugin is it on that page?

Comment: I still get the cross-domain issue.

Comment: Check my answer; I don't think client-side is the way to go here.  My original question was if there was a Razor way to do this and the solution I found does what I was looking for.